# Yadugiri in Puranas

Tags: puranas, sri-vaishnava

Yadugiri, the present day Melukote, in Karnataka is a famous piligrimage centre for Vaishnavas. Ramanujacharya installed the deity Cheluva Narayana in 12th century. It is said that Lord Dattatreya preached Vedas here. Lord Rama during exile is said to have visited Melukote and worshipped Narayana. Does any purana mention the above events at Melukote?